# Subquery: Help correcting syntax errors

Tags: subquery

I am recieving the following 2 errors when I try to run the below subquery: 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 - Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
SELECT
RIGHT(A.Name,LEN(Name)-5) AS ASSOCIATE
,B.WeekEnding
,COUNT(B.ID)AS Policies
,SUM (B.Amount) AS Premium


FROM
dbo.Users A
INNER JOIN (SELECT*,
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,(12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CreateDate)%7)-6,CreateDate)
WeekEnding
FROM dbo.Policy) B
ON A.User = B.Agent 

WHERE
B.CreateDate >= CONVERT (DATE,GETDATE()))


GROUP BY A.Name, B.WeekEnding
ORDER BY Policies DESC, Premium DESC
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `SELECT` in the subquery. It should be:

```
(SELECT *,
        DATEADD(DAY,(12-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CreateDate)%7)-6,CreateDate) WeekEnding
 FROM dbo.Policy)
```

and you have an extra parenthesis here:

```
WHERE
B.CreateDate >= CONVERT (DATE,GETDATE()))
                                        ^
```